# Travelling twin's clock in twin paradox on the way back

Tags: special-relativity

Suppose the situation of the twin paradox: twin A stays on Earth, the other (B) goes to a star with velocity $v$, and at the beginning of the journey their clocks were synhronized. We know that when A sees the ship arrive at the star, it happens at $t_1$ and at spatial coordinate $x_1$. B sees that he arrived at the star (or the star came to him, if you like) at time $t'_1$ and of course at $x'_1=0$. Immediately after arrival, his speed changes sign (in zero time).

To make things interesting A sets his clock to zero when he sees B arrive at the star, and B also sets his clock to zero when the star arrives to him. I would like to know what B's clock shows in B's frame (while coming back to Earth) when A resets his clock, so that when I do a Lorentz transformation from A's frame to B's, at $t=0$, $t'$ will be the elapsed proper time of B since he started his journey back to Earth with velocity $-v$. Please help me in the calculation, I have been thinking about this for a while, but I haven't gotten far. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you set a clock to zero at some point, then you are merely changing the number by which you measure time by a constant. The world doesn't care about how you keep your records, so nothing physical changes.

Comment: If you figure out $t'$ for the trip there, the result should be the same as for the trip back

Comment: @CuriousOne I believe the issue being referred to is that, if we look simply at the trip back to earth, both twins can remain in a non-accelerating reference frame which seemingly makes it impossible to determine which twin actually moved

Comment: @user155066: You can not go anywhere nor come back from anywhere other than where you are without accelerating.